# Touchpad Pressure Sensitivity with libinput

Tags: ubuntu, elementary-os, touchpad, libinput

I'm trying to increase the pressure required to be put on the touchpad in order for it to move the mouse. I'm not talking about the move speed of the mouse pointer, or the general sensitivity of moving my finger around the touchpad. I'm talking about the *pushing down* action of using the touchpad.

Entering `xinput list` shows that `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` is my touchpad. However `xinput list-probs 11` (11 being the ID given to my touchpad by `xinput list`) I get a list of options that all begin with `libinput`.

Several other askubuntu threads ([such as this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483707/14-04-touchpad-is-too-sensitive)) talk about changing the pressure sensitivity but they all require the `Synaptics Finger` option, which currently isn't available for me.

I don't want to install Synaptics options since the Ubuntu community obviously decided that libinput is better for whatever reason.

I'm running elementary OS 0.4 Loki (64-bit) (built on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

**TLDR**: How do I change the touchpad pressure sensitivity on a Ubunty 16.04 build using libinput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not implemented yet as of Jan 19. Should be in libinput 1.7 though, see
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99355

Comment: the patch is already in the master tree since Jan 10 - 2017

Comment: libinput 1.8.2 shipped with Ubuntu 17.10 but I still can't see how to configure pressure.